# Array: Invalid index

Tags: android, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I am getting a `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2`. There are many questions on SO about this, but none help me. I am building an array that is intended to show "person" vs "person". This is a pseudo structure of how I do this:

```
 Array[0] vs Array[1]
 Array[2] vs Array[3]
 Array[4] vs Array[5]
```

**NOTE:** It is possible to do a parallel array if that would make this easier.

Here is the code I am attempting

```
private void displayCard() {
    HomeItemList = new ArrayList<HomeItem>();
    fightList.whereContainedIn("objectId", itemListCard);
    fightList.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objectId, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null){
              for(int i = 0; i < itemListCard.size(); i=i+2){
                    HomeItem homeItem = new HomeItem();
                    homeItem.setHomeItemID(k);
                    k++;
                    //set Red Array
                    homeItem.setHomeItemRedName(objectId.get(i).getString("Name"));
                    homeItem.setHomeItemRedAge(objectId.get(i).getString("Age"));
                    homeItem.setHomeItemRedRecord(objectId.get(i).getString("Record"));
                    homeItem.setHomeItemRedHeight(objectId.get(i).getString("Height"));
                    homeItem.setHomeItemRedWeight(objectId.get(i).getString("Weight"));
                    homeItem.setHomeItemRedCity(objectId.get(i).getString("Location"));
                    homeItem.setHomeItemRedExp(objectId.get(i).getString("Experience"));

                    //Set Blue Array
                    homeItem.setHomeItemBlueName(objectId.get(i+1).getString("Name"));
                    homeItem.setHomeItemBlueAge(objectId.get(i+1).getString("Age"));
                    homeItem.setHomeItemBlueRecord(objectId.get(i+1).getString("Record"));
                    homeItem.setHomeItemBlueHeight(objectId.get(i+1).getString("Height"));
                    homeItem.setHomeItemBlueWeight(objectId.get(i+1).getString("Weight"));
                    homeItem.setHomeItemBlueCity(objectId.get(i+1).getString("Location"));
                    homeItem.setHomeItemBlueExp(objectId.get(i+1).getString("Experience"));


                    //add the array
                    HomeItemList.add(homeItem);
```

`itemListCard.size()` will change sizes often. Right now, it is 2. This is my LogCat:

```
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
        at com.package.name.databaseFightCard$3.done(databaseFightCard.java:225)
        at com.parse.FindCallback.internalDone(FindCallback.java:45)
        at com.parse.FindCallback.internalDone(FindCallback.java:1)
        at com.parse.Parse$6$1.run(Parse.java:888)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is pointing to the line immediately after `//set Blue Array`. I understand that because arrays start with 0, what I don't understand is how to structure it.

Comment: Something is off here... based on the code shown above, at the line just after "//set Blue Array"... i+1 should always be an odd number. But the exception reports that i+1=2.  Is i being modified elsewhere in that loop?

Comment: In your for-loop you use `itemListCard.size()` but you access the objects with `objectId.get(i)`. Are you pretty sure they have the same number of objects? I would suggest using the same ArrayList both the loop and the accessor methods.

Comment: @Markus Good catch. BUT `itemListCard.size` and `objectId.size` are the same thing.

Comment: I'm guessing we're looking into the wrong code... which line is `databaseFightCard.java:225`?

Comment: `@Override` in the code from above

Comment: Mmh sure? There's no way that line is gonna throw a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`... Maybe you did some changes since you posted that logcat?

Comment: Oh no, It is the line right after `//Set blue array`.

Comment: Please, debug step by step and check the content of `objectId`. Chances are it does not have the length you expect.

Comment: I have already done that. `objectId` is what I expected

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found the problem. +1 for getting me to find it.

Comment: Nice, glad you found out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually a `parse` error. I am using parse.com, and I was using the arrays for the wrong classes. I had to go to my data browser on parse.com and adjust all the `objectids`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `objectId` array has only two elements (positions `0` and `1`), and you're trying to access to position `2` during the second iteration of `for` loop. Check how are you setting `objectId`.

Posting code regarding `objectId` would be helpful too.

Comment: I understand this is what is happening.